# Trying to send data via POST using Angular to cURL

Tags: php, angular, curl

I'm trying to send data but it fails everytime.
Smehow when i send it from Angular to cURL it says Undefined Index (which i know most likely the variable is empty or isn't sending)

**inicio.ts**:

```
insertar() {
   this.fname = this.Form.value.fname;
   this.email = this.Form.value.email;
    this.http.post('http://localhost/curl/config/config.php', {
      fname : this.fname,
      email: this.email,
    }).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.router.navigate(['/inicio']);
    }, error => {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  }
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

# An HTTP GET request example
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth- 
Token');
header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$url = 'http://localhost/curl/api/rest.php';
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($postdata, true); 
print_r($data);

if(isset($_POST['fname']) && $_POST['email']){
    $data = [
        "fname" => $_POST['fname'],
        "email" => $_POST['email'],
        ];
}

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$id = [
    "id" => $_POST['id']];
}


switch ($method) {
    case 'GET':
         // not ready
        break;
        case 'POST':
        postData($url,$method,$data);
        break;
        case 'PUT':
        # code...
        break;
        case "DELETE":
         // not ready
        break;

    default:
        //echo json_encode(['Error'=>'Un Error ha ocurrido']);
        break;
}
function postData($url,$method,$data){
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
   $response = curl_exec($ch);

   if(!$response){
       return false;
   } else {
      print_r($response);
   }
   curl_close($ch);

}
```

So i'm missing something in my php file? because i think there's something which stops or doesn't recognize the data i'm sending it.
Edit:  if i use terminal and i execute

```
curl -X POST <url> -d param:value -d param2:value2
```

it works

**Second Edit**: 
Now it works in the config.php file but when i'm trying to send the information from $data it sends empty.

**API code**:

```
<?php 

header('content-type:application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
include ('../config/conn.php');

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");



switch ($method) {
    case 'GET':
        get($conexion);
        break;
    case 'POST':
        post($conexion,$postdata);
        break;
    case 'PUT':
        put();
        break;
    case 'DELETE':
       delete($conexion,$postdata);
        break;    

    default:
        # code...
        break;
}


function get($conexion){

   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_users';
$resultado = pg_query($conexion,$sql);
while ($rows = pg_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    $array[] = $rows;
}
echo json_encode($array);
}



function post($conexion,$postdata){
//It displays as empty string
echo $postdata;

 /*
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_users(fname,email) VALUES('".$fname."','".$email."')";
 $resultado = pg_query($conexion,$sql);  
 close($conexion);  
 */   
}

function put(){

}
function delete($conexion,$postdata){
    parse_str($postdata, $arr);
    $idn = $arr['id'];
    $id = (int)$idn;
    echo $id;


}

function close($conexion){
    pg_close($conexion);
}


 ?>
```

Comment: Are you getting values in $data for config.php

Comment: @Chrisshi No, i'm getting the error of undefined index among fname and email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When postign json content, you cannot use `$_POST` variable

Try something like this

```
$jsonBody= file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($jsonBody, true);
```

`$data` should be an associative array with `fname` and `email` keys

Comment: Kinda worked. Now how can i split them by their keys? The Output was as String "fname=test&email=testemail%40gmail.com" (Somehow the "@" didn't pass well)

Comment: @Neto_Lozano The output of what exactly?

Comment: Nevermind, now it appears as:  Array
(
    [fname] => testing test
    [email] => test@gmail.com
). The problem is when i'm sending that information to my API it displays as empty (i used the same $jsonBody= file_get_contents('php://input'), except for the json_decode);

Comment: @Neto_Lozano If you don't decode it it's just a string... update your question with the latest code and the exact problem

Comment: The Code has been Updated!

Comment: I see, i added http_build_query($data) but in the API appears as fname=testing+test&email=test%40gmail.com

Comment: Perfect it worked! Do you know how i can split them in 2 variables? Because it appears as: fname=testing test&email=test@gmail.com

Comment: I think you could use the `$_POST` variable directly instead of `php://input` in your API. Otherwise you'll need to manually split the string on `&` , or any other separator that you provide to `http_build_query`